# Remove main.js from Liferay Theme

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

I currently fight to reduce the amount of requests on page load. The main.js is not used in our custom theme, but still gets loaded.

So how can I remove the theme's main.js, so that the browser won't attempt to load it?
Overwriting it with an empty file in our theme is not an solution (wont reduce request count).

Comment: Are you sure that this operation generate a request? I think main.js is append to jsp directly server side. Can you see a specific request for main.js in your browser console?

Comment: the main.js is included with a <script type="text/javascript" src="..../main.js?...."> tag, which the browser then needs to load. I didn't write that tag, LR includes it somewhere deep down and I wasn't able to find that point. I suspect that the theme is threated like a portlet and it's included in the portlet-JS loop in top_js.jspf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find the `main.js` instances in the following places:

In `html/common/themes/bottom.jsp`, (with a hook you can modify this)

```
<script src="<%= HtmlUtil.escape(PortalUtil.getStaticResourceURL(request, themeDisplay.getPathThemeJavaScript() + "/main.js")) %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in `/themes/_unstyled/templates/init.vm` (in your custom theme's `init_custom.vm` you can change this variable)

```
#set ($js_main_file = $htmlUtil.escape($portalUtil.getStaticResourceURL($request, "$javascript_folder/main.js")))
```

and finally in `portal-impl/src/VM_liferay.vm` (this is in the jar file so you might want to go the ext way but i think you may not need to do anything with this file since this is just a macro which is defined, the thing you may want to change is how this macro (sort of function in velocity) is accessed and from where it is accessed)

```
#macro (js $file_name)
    #if ($file_name == $js_main_file)
        <script id="mainLiferayThemeJavaScript" src="$file_name" type="text/javascript"></script>
    #else
        <script src="$file_name" type="text/javascript"></script>
    #end
#end
```

I am not sure if modifying these files would give the behaviour you desire but you may try and find out. I have not tried yet.